# Bounty auto reward on equally qualified answers

Tags: support, bounty

The [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) system has auto rewarding mechanism:

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, *half* the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2.

In this [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55827671/converting-a-mapstring-string-to-a-value-type-with-jedis/55897026#55897026) the grace period is about to end and there are *three* answers with 2 upvotes.

How will the bounty be distributed in a case of multiple equally qualified answers?

I just saw that someone upvoted one of the answers on the previous example, but the the question remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [Stack Exchange FAQ on bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> If two eligible answers have the same score, the older answer is chosen.

Comment: Actually there 2 almost in the same time (less than 1 minute apart), so pretend both in same time/minute?

Comment: Times are recorded and are significant at least to the second. "Almost" doesn't cut it.

Comment: And even if in the case of more than answer having exactly the same timestamp down to the second, one of the posts will have a lower post id.